# Objetos DontDestroyOnLoad no me permiten reiniciar la Escena

Tags: c#, unity, unity3d

Estoy trabajando en mi juego de unity y agregue la opcion que con la letra r el juego se reinicie, reinicio la escena con la funcion `SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);`, Estoy funcionaba correctamente hasta que a algunos objetos le agregue el codigo Awake con un DontDestroyOnLoad. Apartir de aahora en vez de reiniciarme la escena como lo hacia antes me saltan errores y el juego sigue corriendo.

No puedo quitar los Awakes porque despues los Instances no me funcionan, ¿Como puedo hacer para reiniciar la escena correctamente?